# Not null reference a null or transient value

Tags: spring-boot, one-to-one, notnull

So i am trying to achieve oneToone relationship between two entity classes.First class is a customer entity class which have two foreign keys buyer_id and seller_id.So what i want initially is that when the user fills the initial credentials in the website the buyer_id and seller_id field should be null and after the user fills the required information for the buyer or seller i will update the row of the corresponding customer and add the buyer_id and seller_id.But when i try to create a customer entry i am getting this error that buyer_id cannot be null?

This is my customer table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
    public enum Status{
        ACTIVE,
        IN_ACTIVE
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id",nullable = true,referencedColumnName = "id",updatable = true)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private Seller seller_id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional = true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id", nullable = true,referencedColumnName="id",updatable = true)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private Buyer buyer_id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional = false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = false,unique = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user_id;



    public Buyer getBuyer_id() {
        return buyer_id;
    }

    public void setBuyer_id(Buyer buyer_id) {
        this.buyer_id = buyer_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    String name;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "Status")
    private Status status;

    public Customer(String name,Status status){
        this.name=name;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Customer(){

    }
    public Seller getSeller_id() {
        return seller_id;
    }

    public void setSeller_id(Seller seller_id) {
        this.seller_id = seller_id;
    }

    public User getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(User user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user_id = user;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


This is my buyer table
@Entity
@Table(name="Buyer")
public class Buyer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id") private long id;

    @Column(name = "GSTIN")
    String GSTIN;

    @Column(name = "Legal_Document")
    @Lob
    private byte[] legalDocument;

  

    

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    mappedBy = "buyer_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Customer customer;



    @Column(name = "Authorized_person_name")
    String authorized_person_name;

    @Column(name = "Authorized_person_email")
    String authorized_person_email;
}
```

This is my seller table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Seller")
public class Seller {
    @Id
    @Nullable
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "GSTIN")
    private String GSTIN;

    @Column(name = "GST_Document")
    @Lob
    private byte[] gst_document;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                mappedBy = "seller_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Customer customer;

//    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
//               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
//                mappedBy = "sellerId")
//    @JsonIgnore
//    private PickupAddress pickupAddress;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;


    public String getGSTIN() {
        return GSTIN;
    }

    public void setGSTIN(String GSTIN) {
        this.GSTIN = GSTIN;
    }

    public byte[] getGst_document() {
        return gst_document;
    }

    public void setGst_document(byte[] gst_document) {
        this.gst_document = gst_document;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



}
```

Comment: You need to mention seller, buyer and user instead of seller_id, buyer_id and user_id. Spring will automatically map the values and get the details. And while saving data to db, you need to pass complete valid objects of these entities into the setters not just the id's.

Comment: i have done it but same error is coming...what i want is that the foreign keys like seller and buyer should be null initially but when customer enters the required details i can update that particular row in the customer table and add seller or buyer foreign keys.